# from test, panic: sql: connection returned that was never out

Tags: unit-testing, go

I get the following panic at run time of my test:

```
panic: sql: connection returned that was never out
```

**The test**

The actual test is part of a [test suite](https://godoc.org/github.com/stretchr/testify/suite), and is defined thus:

```
func (suite *RowsSuite) TestReadFrom_SanityTest() {
    t := suite.T()

    rows := new(sql.Rows)
    *rows = suite.nonEmptyRows

    assert.True(t, rows.Next())
    // hit the function like it's supposed to be hit
    err := ReadFrom(rows,
        suite.fnStubFalse,
        suite.spots[0],
        suite.spots[1],
        suite.spots[2])

    // There better be no error
    if !assert.Nil(t, err) {
        t.Error(err.ToString(false))
    }

}
```

**The code under test**

I'm responsible for testing this function:

```
// ReadFrom reads values from `rows` into `valuePlaceholders`
func ReadFrom(rows *sql.Rows,
    readerFunc func(rowIndex int, readValues ...interface{}) (bool, *errors.ErrorSt),
    valuePlaceholders ...interface{}) (err *errors.ErrorSt) {

    rowLine := 1
    for rows.Next() {
        if err := rows.Scan(valuePlaceholders...); err != nil {
            return errors.Database().AddDetails(err.Error(), valuePlaceholders)
        }
        if readerFunc != nil {
            skipRest, err := readerFunc(rowLine, valuePlaceholders...)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            if skipRest {
                break
            }
        }
        rowLine++
    }
    if rowLine == 1 {
        return errors.Get(appErrors.ACNoRows)
    }
    return nil
}
```

**Setup**

`suite.fnStubFalse` is simply a function stub that returns `false,nil`
`suite.spots` is simply an `[]*interface{}` of size 3. Simply put, it's three spots to `Scan` to.

The rest of the definitions relevant to the test are defined in this helper method which is invoked on suite setup:

```
func (suite *RowsSuite) setupRowStates() {
    // for throwing fatal error right away
    t := suite.T()
    // fire up the mock
    suite.db, suite.mock, suite.err = sqlmock.New()
    // if there's an error, fatally throw it right away!
    if !assert.Nilf(t,
        suite.err,
        "Error with initializing a stub database connection") {
        t.Fatal()
    }

    // define the possible expectant result sets
    noRows := sqlmock.NewRows(suite.columns)
    nonEmptyRows := sqlmock.NewRows(suite.columns).
        AddRow(381, "Beans", 1.59).
        AddRow(34981, "Frozen Pizza", 5.49)

    // define our sql behavior
    regex := "^SELECT (.+) FROM items$"
    sql := "SELECT (item_id, item_name, item_price) FROM items"

    specificRegex := "^SELECT (.+) FROM items (.+)$"
    specificSQL := `
    SELECT (item_id, item_name, item_price) FROM items i
    INNER JOIN stock s
    ON s.item_id = i.item_id
    WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(s.stock_time) > TIME_TO_SEC(NOW())`

    // setup general query to return non-empty rows
    suite.mock.ExpectQuery(regex).
        WillReturnRows(nonEmptyRows)
    // setup specific query to return empty rows
    suite.mock.ExpectQuery(specificRegex).
        WillReturnRows(noRows)

    // hit both queries right now and store the state of their
    //  return values, terminating right away on any errors
    var err error
    rows, err := suite.db.Query(sql)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
    suite.nonEmptyRows = *rows
    emptyRows, err := suite.db.Query(specificSQL)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
    suite.noRows = *emptyRows

}
```

**The full error**

This monstrosity:

```
Running tool: C:\Go\bin\go.exe test -timeout 30s ezsoft\apiserver_sdk\db -run ^TestRowsSuite$

panic: sql: connection returned that was never out

goroutine 22 [running]:
database/sql.(*DB).putConn(0xc04204d400, 0xc04212a080, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc04213de01)
    C:/Go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1158 +0x351
database/sql.(*driverConn).releaseConn(0xc04212a080, 0x0, 0x0)
    C:/Go/src/database/sql/sql.go:383 +0x53
database/sql.(*driverConn).(database/sql.releaseConn)-fm(0x0, 0x0)
    C:/Go/src/database/sql/sql.go:706 +0x45
database/sql.(*Rows).close(0xc04212a100, 0x899be0, 0xc042048380, 0x0, 0x0)
    C:/Go/src/database/sql/sql.go:2932 +0x159
database/sql.(*Rows).awaitDone(0xc04212a100, 0x89d260, 0xc042050b00, 0x0, 0x0)
    C:/Go/src/database/sql/sql.go:2588 +0x12f
created by database/sql.(*Rows).initContextClose
    C:/Go/src/database/sql/sql.go:2572 +0xa3
FAIL    ezsoft/apiserver_sdk/db 0.429s
Error: Tests failed.
```

**Third-party libraries used**

I use [`testify`](https://godoc.org/github.com/stretchr/testify) and [`go-sqlmock`](https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock) (I'm probably shooting myself in the foot by using it to simply stub queries, because I'm having to jump through hoops in the setup.)

I have no idea what's causing this fail. *When I delete the test, and run the suite itself, everything works*

Comment: If it helps, the offending error is in the go source here: https://golang.org/src/database/sql/sql.go#L1232 Which translates to, somehow something is returning a connection to the database connection pool that was never out (given out). Or perhaps it was given out, but never put to use.

Comment: Now that you mention that, I'm trying to do the following :

- setup two distinct row states as members of `suite`, in setup. To do this, and to avoid shallow-copy later on, I saved them as `sql.Row` instead of `*sql.Row`
- in test, I try to deep-copy one of them (the one I want) via setting up a new pointer, and setting what it points to to the original state. 

*This may decouple the `*sql.Row` that operations are happening on from any stub connection in the suite*, thus causing the panic

Comment: That's probably it. I wouldn't recommend trying to clone those resources that way, due to the behind-the-scenes resource management that `sql` is trying to do.

Comment: Is there alternative, for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I was overthinking this situation.

I fixed it by storing the two row states *as pointers*, and then setting them in `RowsSuite.SetupTest` (at the test level, not the suite level). From there, I just fetch one of the states in the test, and I was good to go. Namely, instead of this (which would work fine in C++):

```
func (suite *RowsSuite) TestReadFrom_SanityTest() {
    t := suite.T()

    rows := new(sql.Rows)
    *rows = suite.nonEmptyRows

    assert.True(t, rows.Next())
    // hit the function like it's supposed to be hit
    err := ReadFrom(rows,
        suite.fnStubFalse,
        suite.spots[0],
        suite.spots[1],
        suite.spots[2])

    // There better be no error
    if !assert.Nil(t, err) {
        t.Error(err.ToString(false))
    }

}
```

I did this:

```
func (suite *RowsSuite) TestReadFrom_SanityTest() {
    t := suite.T()

    rows := suite.nonEmptyRows

    // hit the function like it's supposed to be hit
    errSt := ReadFrom(rows,
        suite.fnStubFalse,
        suite.spots[0],
        suite.spots[1],
        suite.spots[2])

    // There better be no error
    if !assert.Nil(t, errSt) {
        t.Error(errSt.ToString(false))
    }

}
```

where `nonEmptyRows` is one of the states set just before the test is run

Comment: Aha, by manually creating `new(sql.Rows)` it was creating it with zero values and would trip that panic. Guess you can't just go about creating another packages structs without proper initialization, which stands to reason, but is something possible to forget.